# Where can I find the rules for "Deer Hunters Challenge"?

Tags: deer-hunters-challenge

I recently bought a copy of "Deer Hunters Challenge" at a rummage sale. While it *looks* like all the pieces are there, no instructions were included with the game.

Several Google searches with various terms such as "Deer Hunters Challenge board game rules" and "instructions deer hunters challenge board game" yielded only a small number of online sales of the game and similarly themed games.

I found several sites for board game rules by searching "board game rules" but none of them turned up results for this obscure game.

Where can I find the rules for this game?

To aid in identification, given the similarly themed and named games, here is part of the top of the box including the name and the maker:

[image: Deer Hunters Challenge]

Comment: @Thunderforge, they sell it at Amazon, so it must exist: https://www.amazon.com/Deer-Hunters-Challenge-Board-Game/dp/B00YLSIFNQ

Comment: Good luck on this I can't seem to find any information on the publisher and from what I can see the game was published in 1997 so finding information may be hard.

Answer (score 3):

I found the game for sale on a site called [cauf.com](https://cauff.com/product/deer-hunters-challenge-board-game/) that says

> Since we are located within the heart of Ohio’s Amish community, we have access to some of the most amazing and high quality products directly from the manufacturer, saving you money.

And there is a Six Mills Game Company in Ohio, or at least there used to be. [Sites that list business information](http://www.ibegin.com/directory/us/ohio/millersburg/six-mills-game-co-8076-state-route-241/) aren't always good at staying up to date. But since the game is still for sale, it seems like a good bet.

> Six Mills Game Co, 8076 State Route 241, Millersburg, Ohio 44654
>   (330) 674-2541

You can try contacting them for the rules. And maybe the company name/location is just coincidence, because I couldn't find anything else about them.  Good luck!